# removeEventListener not removing from getEventListeners

Tags: javascript, events, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener, topaz-signatures

I am trying to capture a signature response to a Topaz Signature pad. I have the following code in JavaScript. When I call `removeEventListener`, why is it adding another SignResponse instead of removing it from the `getEventListeners(document)` object?

[image: Watch Window]

```
var self = this;

function SignResponse(myself, event) {
    //do stuff
}

document.removeEventListener('SignResponse', SignResponse.bind(this, self), false);

document.addEventListener('SignResponse', SignResponse.bind(this, self), false);
```

Comment: I think your event handler has too many parameters. I would suggest simplifying your example, as it does add an event listener back. I understand that you expect there to only be one remaining after that but, your problem is not adding an event listener.  The event handler should ideally be just the function name, with that function / method accepting an event parameter. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: Every time you call `functionname.bind()` you create a new function. So the function you're removing isn't the same one that you added. You need to give a name to the function when you add it, and use that same name when trying to remove.